# Using Autofac in Ninject

Tags: ninject, autofac

Hello I have many many projects in many solutions and all use Ninject as IoC container. Common libraries have Ninject modules, the applications (like console application) usually have modules too and combine the modules in one StandardKernel. Now I have to change all common libraries to Autofac.

Let's say I make modifications and use Autofac (by defining Autofac modules) in a project named A (common library). A is referenced in project B (a console application) which still uses Ninject.  Let's assume that for now I do not want to modify project B too much and I want to leave Ninject there.

It is possible to use Autofac modules from project A when in the end I use Ninject's StandardKernel in the "final" project B?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no adapter that just "converts" one IoC format to the other. I don't think Ninject supports Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection format registrations, either, so trying to use the `IServiceCollection` from there as a bridge also won't work.

Unfortunately, I think you're stuck. You'll have to do it all at once. Sorry.